# in database how to store data with multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have database with table T-Shirt. The table have id , name, price , size ,image, quantity and price
The t shirt can have different than one size (s ,m l ,xl) how can I store the different size for the same data. for example 

 
id:101
name:Iron Man T-Shirt
size: xs, s, m , l
price:15
quantity: 25
image: im.jpg

Comment: Have a table `SKU` that has an entry for every SKU. It links back to some productID ("Iron Man T-Shirt"), but has separate rows for all different sizes and colors. You are going to need to keep track of quantities separately anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SET Data Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) for column size

If you want to store quantity for each size you can use [JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) (MySQL 5.7)

Comment: Does not help too much if you need to keep `quantity` separate for each size.

Comment: @Thilo Agree. Updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much that was very helpful I didn't know about json data type unfortunately  my server version: 5.6.17